# Javascript: header is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

I already tried the 2 re-directions in JavaScript, the `window.location.href()` and `header()` but always show me an error:

> ReferenceError: header is not defined

My code from PHP:

```
echo "<script> header('location: index.php');</script>";
```

Comment: `header()` is a php function, that is why it is undefined in JavaScript. Just `header('location: index.php'); exit;` is required. Don't `echo` it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `header()` function in JavaScript. `header()` is a PHP function. Here is one way to redirect using JS:

```
echo "<script> window.location.href = 'index.php'; </script>";
```

Or in PHP:

```
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

Comment: wrong use of codes. thank you. I forgot that header() is for php.

Comment: what if I did not consider the `exit;` is that ok ?

Comment: No, because if you have code below `header()`, it would still execute.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use jquery
try this

```
echo  header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve with Below Code:

For JavaScript in PHP:

```
echo '<script>window.location.href="YOURURL.COM"</script>';
```

For Simple PHP:

```
echo header('Location: '."YOURURL.COM");
```

Answer (score 0):

`header()` is a php function. and `header()` must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

```
<?php
header("Location: index.php"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

in js try,  `window.location.href = "index.php"`        //redirectUrl